# Closed subspace of $L^{p}( [a,b])$ consisting of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm wondering if a closed subspace of $L^p [a,b](1\leq p<\infty)$ consisting of continuous functions must be finite-dimensional?

I already know it's true for $L^2([a,b]): $ [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014437/closed-subspace-consisting-of-continuous-functions-in-l20-1-is-finite-d)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the OP's question is yes, a closed subspace $M$ of $L_p([a,b])$ consisting of continuous functions is finite dimensional. Since $M\subset\mathcal{C}([a,b])$, then $M\subset L_\infty$ and the result follows from a Theorem by Grothendieck (see, Rudin, W., Functional Analysis, McGraw Hill, Chapter 5.)

> ***Theorem:*** Suppose $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is a finite measure space, $M$ closed in $L_p(\mu)$ for some $0< p<\infty$ and $M\subset L_\infty(\mu)$. Then
> $M$ is finite dimensional.

The theorem above  follows from the $L_2(\mu)$ case as we show below.

*Sketch of the proof $1\leq p<\infty$:*  Without loss of generality assume $\mu(X)=1$. The case $p=2$ is the subject of this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4016272/121671).

Notice that for all $1\leq r<\infty$, $L_\infty(\mu)\subset L_r(\mu)$  and that the inclusion map $\iota_r:f\mapsto f$ is injective and a continuous operator since $\|f\|_r=0$ iff $f=0$ $\mu$-almost surely, and
$$\|\iota_r (f)\|_r=\|f\|_r\leq \|f\|_\infty$$

If $M$ closed in $L_p(\mu)$ for some $1\leq p<\infty$, then $M$ is also closed in $L_\infty(\mu)$: suppose $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset M$ converges to some $f\in L_\infty(\mu)$, i.e. $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, then
$$\|f_n-f\|_p\leq\|f_n-f\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
Since $M$ is closed in $L_p(\mu)$, it follows that $f\in M$.
An application of the  open map theorem yields that $\iota^{-1}_p:(M,\|\;\|_p)\rightarrow (M,\|\;\|_\infty)$ is also bounded. Thus, there is a constant $K>0$ such that
$$\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|_\infty\leq K\|f\|_p,\qquad f\in M$$

- If $1\leq p\leq 2$, then for any $f\in M$
  $$\|f\|_2\leq\|f\|_\infty\leq K\|f\|_p\leq
  K\|f\|_2$$
  Thus $M$ is also closed in $L_2(\mu)$, and then the result in the posting cited above can be used.
- If $2<p<\infty$ then
  \begin{align}
  \|f\|_p\leq\|f\|^{1-2/p}_\infty\|f\|^{p/2}_2
  \end{align}
  It follows that
  $$\|f\|_\infty\leq K\|f\|_p\leq K\|f\|^{1-2/p}_\infty\|f\|^{p/2}_2$$
  and so,
  $$\|f\|_2\leq \|f\|_\infty\leq K^{p/2}\|f\|_2$$
  Consequently $M$ is closed in $L_2(\mu)$.
- If $0<p<1$, the space $L_p(\mu)$  equipped with translation invariant metric $d_p(f, g)=\|f-g\|^p_p=\int|f-g|^p\,d\mu$ is complete metrizable linear space (an $F$-space). It is easy to prove that  a set in $B\subset (L_p,d_p)$  is bounded iff $\sup\{\|f\|_p: f\in B\}<\infty$. It follows that a linear operator $P:(L_\infty(\mu),\|\;\|_\infty)\rightarrow (L_p(\mu),d_p)$ is bounded iff there is a constant $k>0$ such that $\|Pf\|_p\leq k\|f\|_\infty$. Conversely, a linear operator $R:(L_p(\mu),d_p)\rightarrow(L_\infty(\mu),\|\;\|_\infty)$ is bounded iff there is a contant $K>0$ such that $\|Rf\|_\infty\leq K\|f\|_p$. The proof of the Theorem for this case as we can see, becomes similar to that of $1\leq p<2$.

Comment: This proof is true for $1\leq p<2$.However If $2<  p$,we can't conclude that M is closed in $L^2$ since $\lVert f\rVert_2 \leq K\lVert f\rVert_p$ is always true,and a closed space in $L^p,p>2$ doesn't necessarily closed in $L^2$

Comment: Nice reduction to $p=2.$ !! (+)

Comment: On $L^p(0,\infty)$ it is easy as one may consider the closed linear span of the functions $f_n(x)=f(x-n),$ where $f(x)=\min{x,1-x}.$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Concerning $L^p((0,1)$ I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231282/closed-infinite-dimensional-linear-subspace-of-lp0-1-consisting-of-contin) I am not certain it is correct.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Thanks for your comment. In fact, as I just found out the problem is solved by a Theorem by  Grothendieck for all $0<p<\infty$, that is in any probability space $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$,  for any $0<p<\infty$,  if $M\subset L_p(\mu)\cap L_\infty(\mu)$ and $M$ closed in $L_p(\mu)$, then $M$ is finite dimensional. I suspect  you already about this.

Comment: I was not aware of the Grothendieck result. It's a nice way of yours to handle the case $p>2.$

Comment: Very nice. We discussed a baby version of that theorem of Grothendieck recently, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432202/8157).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: long time no see... yes, I recall know your posting!

Comment: @OliverDíaz A nice proof!Thank you!

Comment: Dear @OliverDíaz The property of being not dense can be achieved in an artificial way by replacing $X$ with the direct sum $X\oplus X.$

Comment: @OliverDíaz I meant for example  $\ell^1\subset c_0$ is dense and not closed, but $\ell^1\oplus \{0\}\subseteq c_0\oplus c_0$  is not closed and not dense. Or I misunderstood something

Answer (score 4):

The identity map $Id:(X ,\|\cdot\|_\infty) \to (X,\|\cdot\|_p)$ is linear, continuous, and bijective, hence invertible. This implies there is $c>0$ such that $\|x\|_\infty \le c \|x\|_p$ for all $x\in X$.

But this implies $\|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{b-a} \|x\|_\infty \le c \sqrt{b-a} \|x\|_p$ for all $x\in X$. Hence, $X$ is a closed subspace of $L^2$, and hence finite-dimensional.