# Brezis' Exercise 5.29.2: a lemma of Grothendieck

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu (\Omega) < \infty$. Fix $p \in [1, \infty)$ and let $E$ be a closed subspace of $L^p (\Omega)$ such that $E \subset L^\infty (\Omega)$.
>
> 1. Prove that there is a constant $C$ such that
>    $$
>    \|u\|_\infty \le C \|u\|_p
>    \quad \forall u \in E.
>    $$
> 2. Prove that there is a constant $M$ such that
>    $$
>    \|u\|_\infty \le M \|u\|_2
>    \quad \forall u \in E.
>    $$

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

1. Fix $q \in [p, \infty]$. Because $\mu (\Omega) < \infty$, we get
   $$
   \| u \|_p \le (\mu (\Omega))^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}} \|u\|_q
   \quad \forall u \in L^q (\Omega).
   \qquad \qquad (\star)
   $$

We will prove that $E$ is closed in $L^q (\Omega)$. Let $(u_n) \subset E$ and $u \in L^q (\Omega)$ such that $\|u_n-u\|_q \to 0$. By $(\star)$, $\|u_n-u\|_p \to 0$. On the other hand, $E$ is closed in $L^p (\Omega)$. So $u \in E$. It follows that $(E, \| \cdot\|_p)$ and $(E, \| \cdot\|_q)$ are Banach spaces. It follows from $(\star)$ and **Corollary 2.8** in the same book that $\| \cdot\|_p$ and $\| \cdot\|_q$ are equivalent norms on $E$. The claim then follows by picking $q = \infty$.

> **Corollary 2.8.** Let $E$ be a vector space provided with two norms, ||$_1$ and ||$_2$. Assume that $E$ is a Banach space for both norms and that there exists a constant $C \geq 0$ such that
> $$
> \|x\|_2 \leq C\|x\|_1 \quad \forall x \in E .
> $$
> Then the two norms are equivalent, i.e., there is a constant $c>0$ such that
> $$
> \|x\|_1 \leq c\|x\|_2 \quad \forall x \in E .
> $$

2. If $2 \ge p$, then the claim follows from (1.). Now we assume $2 < p$. We fix some $q \in (p, \infty)$. Then $2 < p < q < \infty$. Then there is $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ such that $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1-\alpha}{q}$. By [interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality?useskin=vector#Generalization_with_more_than_two_functions),
   $$
   \|u\|_p \le \|u\|_2^\alpha \|u\|_q^{1-\alpha}
   \quad \forall u \in E.
   $$

By $(\star)$, $\|u\|_q \le (\mu (\Omega))^{\frac{1}{q}} \|u\|_\infty$ for all $u \in E$. By (1.), $\|u\|_\infty \le C \|u\|_p$ for all $u \in E$. Then
$$
\|u\|_p \le \|u\|_2^\alpha (C(\mu (\Omega))^{\frac{1}{q}} \|u\|_p)^{1-\alpha}
\quad \forall u \in E.
$$

Then
$$
\|u\|^\alpha_p \le \|u\|_2^\alpha (C(\mu (\Omega))^{\frac{1}{q}})^{1-\alpha}
\quad \forall u \in E.
$$

Then
$$
\|u\|_p \le \|u\|_2 (C(\mu (\Omega))^{\frac{1}{q}})^{(1-\alpha)/\alpha}
\quad \forall u \in E.
$$

Then
$$
\|u\|_\infty \le C \|u\|_p \le C  (C(\mu (\Omega))^{\frac{1}{q}})^{(1-\alpha)/\alpha}  \|u\|_2
\quad \forall u \in E.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Your solution seems correct. I think that you can use the closed map theorem too. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4553558/121671) is a related posting

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you so much for your verification! I'm aware of [open mapping theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)). Could you elaborate on your closed map theorem?

Comment: I meant to say the closed graph theorem. That is what in the link I sent in my previous message is used to get continuity of some linear maps.